# Does Activity#getSystemService call the Application version

Tags: android, dagger

I made my Dagger graph available through the Application's getSystemService() and I assumed that calling this on the activity would call the Application method. Since I never got my graph, I figured activity does not call through to the application. Currently I have

```
@Override
public Object getSystemService(@NonNull String name) {
    if(Injector.matchesService(name)){
        return getApplication().getSystemService(name);
    }
    return super.getSystemService(name);
}
```

Did I miss something or is this the only solution to access stuff from my Application in my views.